# Waiting for configuring calico service - IBM Cloud Private 2.0.1.2 Installation

Tags: ibm-cloud-private, calico

During the IBM Cloud Private 2.0.1.2 Installation (single node ubuntu 16.04) I encounter the following error:

```
TASK [network : Waiting for configuring calico service] ************************
task path: /installer/playbook/roles/network/tasks/calico.yaml:13
Using module file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ansible/modules/utilities/logic/wait_for.py
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/bash -c 'echo ~ && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/bash -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528987006.29-271366323320242 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1528987006.29-271366323320242="` echo /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528987006.29-271366323320242 `" ) && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> PUT /tmp/tmpMpYzjY TO /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528987006.29-271366323320242/wait_for.py
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/bash -c 'chmod u+x /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528987006.29-271366323320242/ /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528987006.29-271366323320242/wait_for.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/bash -c '/usr/bin/python /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528987006.29-271366323320242/wait_for.py; rm -rf "/root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1528987006.29-271366323320242/" > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
failed: [127.0.0.1 -> 127.0.0.1] (item=127.0.0.1) => {
    "elapsed": 120, 
    "failed": true, 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "active_connection_states": [
                "ESTABLISHED", 
                "SYN_SENT", 
                "SYN_RECV", 
                "FIN_WAIT1", 
                "FIN_WAIT2", 
                "TIME_WAIT"
            ], 
            "connect_timeout": 5, 
            "delay": 10, 
            "exclude_hosts": null, 
            "host": "127.0.0.1", 
            "path": "/etc/cni/net.d/10-calico.conflist", 
            "port": null, 
            "search_regex": null, 
            "sleep": 1, 
            "state": "present", 
            "timeout": 120
        }
    }, 
    "item": "127.0.0.1", 
    "msg": "Timeout when waiting for file /etc/cni/net.d/10-calico.conflist"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
127.0.0.1                  : ok=205  changed=68   unreachable=0    failed=1   

Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 12 minutes, 37 seconds

user@user:/opt/ibm-cloud-private-ce-2.1.0.2/cluster$
```

I tried the suggestions from the similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47210290/how-do-i-solve-the-waiting-for-calico-node-service-error-message) but none of it worked for me, which is maybe due to the slightly different error message. 
I don't understand why it times out while waiting for a file that is on this machine.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this issue should be cause by your specify the ICP node IP to '127.0.0.1' in ICP hosts file. Normally, we can not use '127.0.0.1' as the ICP node IP, thanks.